# Strapi CMS - how to install it on cpanel?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, headless, strapi

I am trying to install Strapi headless CMS on my Cpanel Shared server and I failed.
I have SSh Access, 
I have nodeJs Access on my cpanel 
Anyone know how to install **Strapi** and get access to Admin panel?

Edit: I managed to install it and runnning fine on server but when I close the SSH, it shows me 503 error on my browser ( because of htaccess)
How to keep the process running ?

Comment: Maybe using pm2?
BTW, on a similar setup, I have issues with port redirection. Can you share your htaccess if yours is solving this issue?

Comment: Same port problem

Comment: Were you able to resolve it properly?